# How to set the button width with a style?

Tags: android

Here is my current code:

```
<style name="ApplicationStyle" parent="AppBaseTheme">
  <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/CKButton</item>
</style>
<style name="CKButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_button</item>
  <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
  <item name="android:layout_width">155dp</item>
 </style>
```

The background and font size are applied correctly to every button in the app, except the width. How can I set the width of all of my buttons with a style?

Edit: 
Here is the rest of the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".WelcomeActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Welcome_Foglalas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Időpontfoglalás" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show your lay out, if your setting the width param in the xml it will override the width in the style

Comment: please post your complete layout codes. It helps in clarifying your error and needs quickly

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: moved the width declaration to the "ApplicationStyle" and deleted the width attribute in the activity

Comment: How ? Like this `<item name="android:layout_height">25dp</item>` ?